# Is this code thread safe, are there better ways to implement it?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
public class MySystem {
    private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> disabledList = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void toggle(int id) {
        synchronized (disabledList) {
            if (disabledList.containsKey(id)) {
                disabledList.remove(id);
            } else {
                disabledList.put(id);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isInactive(int id) {
      return disabledList.containsKey(id);
    }

}
```

It is possible that multiple threads can call the `toggleId` method. Is the above code thread-safe? Is there a better data structure I can use like `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Ideally I'd like to get rid of the synchronized block, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Which `ConcurrentHashSet` implementation is your code using?

Comment: Erm ... calling your class `System` is a bit dodgy because it will shadow the `java.lang.System` class.

Comment: But I need to wrap the check for whether the hashset contains the id and the code for removing the id in a sycnhronized block, otherwise there could be a race condition when another thread (say t1) calls remove after thread t2 has checked contains?

Comment: Renamed the class, it was only for illustration purposes.

Comment: Is there any other code using `disabledList`?

Comment: yes, but only reading from it

Comment: That code will likely need to be synchronized as well.

Comment: I'd declare `disabledList` a `final`. Also, is this a `List`, or a `Map`? If latter, don't you want to do `.put(key, value)`? Have you taken a look at `putIfAbsent` contract on CHM?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the concurrent classes in Java do NOT lock themselves to implement thread safety.  Therefore you can't rely on `synchronized` in one place in your code to synchronize with the rest of the access to that object.

Quoting from the Java docs for `ConcurrentHashMap`:

> However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access. This class is fully interoperable with Hashtable in programs that rely on its thread safety but not on its synchronization details.

The Java doc for `CopyOnWriteArrayList` doesn't specify its locking characteristics, but since it's copy-on-write, I doubt it's taking a lock internally.  I wouldn't count on it in production code, certainly.

Comment: Are you saying that the isInactive method also needs to be marked as synchronized?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  This also destroys the concurrency in the map.  You might as well use a plain old synchronized map at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Your `toggleId()` is thread-safe *in isolation*.

What I mean by that is, if an odd number of threads call `toggleId(i)` for the same `i` at the same time, then the end-result will be that the `i` is toggled, and if an even number call it at the same time, then the end result will be a no-op.

But what about it's relationship to `isInactive()`?  What does it mean if thread A calls `isInactive(i)`, and then thread B calls `toggleId(i)` before thread A is able to act on the value that was returned by `isInactive(i)`?

---

> I'd like to get rid of the synchronized block, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

In a word, no.  It would only be possible if `ConcurrentHashMap` implemented a thread-safe `toggleId`-like function for you, but I don't see anything in its API that fits.  `disabledList.putIfAbsent(...)` does *half* the job, but there is no `putIfAbsentOrDeleteIfPresent(...)` method.